# WPF and ASP.net webmethod Upload file progress

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-web-api, progress-bar

I have a WPF application which is messaging with my server using ASP.net web method. I have also file uploading functionality on it. But when I uploading a file to asp.net webmethod, my wpf application being locked. I used the standart **Async** method which generated automatically by asp.net webmethod, but it gives me only method result. I want to implement **Progress bar** about uploading status to server. Attaching my asp.net and WPF upload codes here.

WPF upload code:

```
private async void Upload_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fileDialog.DefaultExt = ".jpg"; // Required file extension 
        fileDialog.Filter = "Image files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.jfif|PDF Files|*pdf|Outlook file|*.msg"; // Optional file extensions
        if (FilesGrid.Items.Count > 4)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Maximum allowed file count is 5\n" +
                                "Please delete File to upload other Files.");
            return;
        }

        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var size = new FileInfo(fileDialog.FileName).Length;
            if (size > 2000000)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File Size cannot be more than 2 MB");
                return;
            }
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
            System.IO.StreamReader(fileDialog.FileName);

            //Get the name of the File.
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileDialog.FileName);

            //Get the content type of the File.
            string contentType = "Image";

            //Read the file data into Byte Array.
            //BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.InputStream);
            //byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);

            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName);

            //Call the Web Service and pass the File data for upload.
            var s = await service.UploadFileAsync(fileName, contentType, bytes, ldap_mapping_id);

            string uplo = s.Body.UploadFileResult;

            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(uplo);
            string id = "";
            string name = "";
            foreach (XmlNode item in xmlDocument.ChildNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode child in item.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (child.Name == "id")
                    {
                        id = child.InnerText;
                    }
                    if (child.Name == "name")
                    {
                        name = child.InnerText;
                    }
                }
            }

            var newAllFiles = new myGridClass
            {
                id = id,
                name = name
            };

            //allFiles.Add(newAllFiles);
            FilesGrid.Items.Add(newAllFiles);
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File cannot be uploaded. Please contact to your support team");
        return;
    }
}
```

ASP.net WebMethod code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string UploadFile(string fileName, string contentType, byte[] bytes, int ldap_mapping_id)
{
    try
    {
        string todayPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Uploads\\" + DateTime.Today.Year + "\\" + DateTime.Today.Month + "\\" + DateTime.Today.Day + "\\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(todayPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(todayPath);
        }
        //Save the Byte Array as File.
        string filePath = todayPath + fileName;
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
        string UrlScheme = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection ? "https://" : "http://";
        string fileUrl = UrlScheme + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + ":" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port.ToString() + "/Uploads/" + DateTime.Today.Year + "/" + DateTime.Today.Month + "/" + DateTime.Today.Day + "/" + fileName;
        var attEntities = new attachment
        {
            file_src = fileUrl,
            ldap_mapping_id = ldap_mapping_id,
            file_path = filePath
        };

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string resultXML = "<Result>";
        var context = new HOCEntities();
        var newHoc = context.attachments.Add(attEntities);
        context.SaveChanges();
        resultXML += "<id>" + attEntities.id.ToString() + "</id>";
        resultXML += "<name>" + fileName + "</name>";
        resultXML += "</Result>";
        return resultXML;
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
            foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "WPF upload code" is inside an async method?

Comment: Yes it's, changed code in that way